# Docusaurus and edit - URL - how to modify relativeDocPath?

Tags: docusaurus

I'm very glad that we are using our docusaurus installation. But I have some problems to find out how to change the edit-URL in the docusaurus.config.js.

My setup is: I installed docusaurus under `/opt/ARTOPS_DOKU`

Then I created a clone of our help repo to `/opt/ARTOPS_DOKU/docs/Docu`

In the `docs` section, I modified the following parameters:

```
routeBasePath: /,
editUrl: https://dev.azure.com/Project/_git/Reponame/
```

So the "Edit" button appears, but the URL is pointing to https://dev.azure.com/Project/_git/Reponame/docs/Docu/filename instead of https://dev.azure.com/Project/_git/Reponame/filename

How can this be changed? I played around now for hours, but have no clue.

Played in the docs section with the variables path, `routeBasePath` but nothing worked. The Edit URL is created from `editUrl + relativeDocPath`, so how can I change this?

I see that editURL can be modified:

```
type EditUrlFunction = (params: {
  version: string;
  versionDocsDirPath: string;
  docPath: string;
  permalink: string;
  locale: string;
}) => string | undefined;
```

So what what be the syntax to remove doc/Docu from the Edit-URL?